# Simple toggle not working on iPhone IOS 11.0.3

Tags: jquery, ios

This is a simple toggle, but, I cannot get it to work on IOS. I have added a Fiddle for this code and also a test site.

HTML including all aria and IDs and classes

`<nav id="navigation" aria-label="Section">
            <div class="mobileMenu">
                <button id="menu-toggle" class="anchor-link menu_container"> 
                    MENU
                    <span id="menu_open" class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span id="menu_close" class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav burgerTime" hidden>
                <li data-id="01" class="nav__module nav__chapter-01">

                    <ul class="nav__items">
                        <li> <a class="menu_p01" href="../index.html">Accordion</a> </li>
                        <li> <a class="menu_p02" href="../tabs.html">Tabs</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>`

jQuery to toggle menu items and aria expanded.

`$( "#menu-toggle" ).attr( {
        "aria-expanded": "false"
    } );
    $( "#menu-toggle" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
        $( "body" ).toggleClass( "active" );
        $( ".nav.burgerTime" ).toggle();
        $( this ).attr( "aria-expanded", function( i, attr ) {
            return attr === "true" ? "false" : "true";
        } );
        e.preventDefault();
    } );`

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Deafinitive/gufk4sk5/

Test site
http://www.thehouseofcats.com.au
Screen size needs to be reduce for toggle menu to appear.